# Java OpenCV 3.1 - Exeutable doesnt take snapshot of webcam, whereas code run in NetBeans does

Tags: java, image, opencv, netbeans

I have made a simple program, which makes a snapshot of the default webcam. When I run my program, it runs without error, but doesnt create "test.jpg", whereas when i run it straight from NetBeans, it works perfectly, and creates test.jpg in the project directory. What might cause the issue? The code:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;        

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);

        if (!camera.isOpened()) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        } else {
            Mat frame = new Mat();

            while (true) {
                if (camera.read(frame)) {
                    System.out.println("Captured Frame Width "
                            + frame.width() + " Height " + frame.height());
                    Imgcodecs.imwrite("test.jpg", frame);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        camera.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run it from the command prompt (as opposed to just clicking the .jar) to get stack traces? I suspect that it doesn't find the OpenCV library from the .jars location.